# No se actualizan datos en mi tabla de SQLSERVER

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, servidor, aplicación-web

Trabajando en ASP.NET y SQLSERVER necesito modificar registros en la siguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla Facultad]

Todos mis campos se modifican, exceptuando la columna de 'Código', ese campo siempre queda con el valor asignado al dar de alta un registro, cuando trato de editarlo, el valor se queda igual:

[image: Campos de edición]

Por ejemplo: FIME001 siempre se queda como FIME001 aunque lo edite y quiera darle otro código.

Estoy trabajando bajo el modelo de 3 capas (Usuario, BLL y DAL) y mi código es el siguiente:

BLL

```
        public void modificarFacultad(string codigo, string nombre, DateTime fechaCreacion, int universidad)
        {
            FacultadDAL facultad = new FacultadDAL();
            facultad.modificarFacultad(codigo, nombre, fechaCreacion, universidad);
        }
```

DAL

```
public void modificarFacultad(string codigo, string nombre, DateTime fechaCreacion, int universidad)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\JovanyServer;Database=Escuela;Trusted_connection=true";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "sp_modificarFacultad";
            command.Connection = connection;


            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCodigo", codigo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pNombre", nombre);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pFecha", fechaCreacion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUniversidad", universidad);

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }
```

facultad_u.aspx.cs

```
        public void modificarFacultad()
        {
            FacultadBLL facuBLL = new FacultadBLL();

            string codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
            string nombre = txtNombreFacultad.Text;
            DateTime fechaCreacion = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaCreacion.Text);
            int universidad = int.Parse(ddlUniversidad.SelectedValue);

            facuBLL.modificarFacultad(codigo, nombre, fechaCreacion, universidad);
        }
```

QUERY DB

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_modificarFacultad]

    @pCodigo VARCHAR(10),
    @pNombre VARCHAR(100),
    @pFecha DATE,
    @pUniversidad INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Facultad
    SET codigo = @pCodigo, nombre = @pNombre, fechaCreacion = @pFecha, universidad = @pUniversidad 
    WHERE codigo = @pCodigo
END
```

Cabe aclarar que en mi botón 'Editar' estoy utilizando el método `Eval` precisamente con la variable 'codigo' en la pantalla de usuario:

Usuario

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditar" runat="server" CommandName="Editar" CommandArgument='<%# Eval ("codigo") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Creo que se puede deber a que estoy evaluando el valor 'codigo' y es precisamente el valor que no se edita, aun no logro comprender bien el porqué.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Una posible causa puede ser si el campo código es una clave primaria y tiene tablas relacionadas. Pero sin la definición de la tabla es difícil confirmarlo.

Comment: puede ser que le falte un trim al campo codigo, y otro tema, porque el update hace un set de codigo y a la vez usa en where el mismo valor?? (@pCodigo), decis que el campo codigo no cambia pero si yo cambio el campo codigo vos estas pasando ese valor cambiado

Comment: `SET codigo = @pcodigo` es el valor que quiero cambiar, además de los demás campos, todos se actualizan menos este, la intención de usarlo en el `WHERE` es para evaluarlo y que en mi pantalla de edición se muestre la información ya capturada, aunque creo que por esa misma razón no cambia, probablemente mi forma de hacerlo no es la correcta. Cabe aclarar que "codigo" no es mi llave primaria, si no el ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de leer y analizar mi código pude ver que la mejor manera de hacerlo era evaluar el `ID_Facultad` en lugar del `codigo` de mi tabla `facultad`, además de incluir la variable `ID` en mis instancias y en mi Base de datos, resultando todo de la siguiente manera:

BLL

```
        public void modificarFacultad(int ID, string codigo, string nombre, DateTime fechaCreacion, int universidad)
        {
            FacultadDAL facultad = new FacultadDAL();
            facultad.modificarFacultad(ID, codigo, nombre, fechaCreacion, universidad);
        }
```

DAL

```
public void modificarFacultad(int ID, string codigo, string nombre, DateTime fechaCreacion, int universidad)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\JovanyServer;Database=Escuela;Trusted_connection=true";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "sp_modificarFacultad";
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pID", ID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCodigo", codigo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pNombre", nombre);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pFecha", fechaCreacion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUniversidad", universidad);

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }
```

facultad_u.aspx.cs

```
        public void modificarFacultad()
        {
            FacultadBLL facuBLL = new FacultadBLL();

            int ID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["pID"]);
            string codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
            string nombre = txtNombreFacultad.Text;
            DateTime fechaCreacion = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaCreacion.Text);
            int universidad = int.Parse(ddlUniversidad.SelectedValue);

            facuBLL.modificarFacultad(ID, codigo, nombre, fechaCreacion, universidad);
        }
```

QUERY DB

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_modificarFacultad]

    @pID INT,
    @pCodigo VARCHAR(10),
    @pNombre VARCHAR(100),
    @pFecha DATE,
    @pUniversidad INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Facultad
    SET codigo = @pCodigo, nombre = @pNombre, fechaCreacion = @pFecha, universidad = @pUniversidad 
    WHERE ID_Facultad = @pID
END
```

Usuario

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditar" runat="server" CommandName="Editar" CommandArgument='<%# Eval ("ID_Facultad") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```